# Reading JSON Content

Tags: java, gson, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to scrape some HTML data and it's working out great.  Now I need to pull some JSON content (only JSON, not HTML).  Can I do this easily with jsoup or do I have to do it using another method?  The parsing that jsoup performs is encoding the JSON data so it's not parsing properly with Gson.

Comment: How about an example of the problematic JSON?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While great, [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) is a HTML parser, not a JSON parser, so it is useless in this context. If you ever attempt it, Jsoup will put the returned JSON implicitly in a `<html><head>` and so on. You don't want to have that.  [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a JSON parser, so you definitely need it.

Your concrete problem is likely that you don't know how to feed an URL returning a JSON to Gson. In that case, you need to use [`URL#openStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) to get an `InputStream` of it and use [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) to decorate it into a `Reader` which finally can be fed to [`Gson#fromJson()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Class%29) which accepts a `Reader`.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/foo.json").openStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Data.class);
// ...
```

Comment: That's pretty much how I ended up doing it.  I figured, as you said, that jsoup just wasn't the correct tool for pulling straight JSON data.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe seven years ago this was true --Jsoup will put the returned JSON implicitly in a <html><head>--, but today, Jsoup can be used to fetch JSON data. See my example.

Answer (score 4):

Jsoup is not designed for parsing JSON. Use Gson(or any other java JSON library).
For getting remote content with Jsoup use this:

```
Connection  con = HttpConnection.connect(url);
con.method(Method.POST).data(data.params).ignoreContentType(true);
Response resp = con.execute();
String body = resp.body();
```

Answer (score 4):

Jsoup does not parse JSON, but it can be used to fetch JSON data easily.

```
package com.zetcode;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

class TimeData {

    private String time;
    private Long milliseconds_since_epoch;
    private String date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TimeData{" + "time=" + time + ", milliseconds_since_epoch=" 
                + milliseconds_since_epoch + ", date=" + date + '}';
    }
}


public class GsonReadWebPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String webPage = "http://time.jsontest.com";

        String data = Jsoup.connect(webPage).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TimeData td = gson.fromJson(data, TimeData.class);

        System.out.println(td);
    }
}
```

The example reads JSON data from `http://time.jsontest.com` with JSoup
and parses JSON with Gson. To execute this example, you need Jsoup
and Gson dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

An old question but struggled a bit to figure this out. Jsoup can fetch the JSON data if you set `ignoreContentType` to `true`. However, it still wraps the JSON content in HTML tags like this.

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
{ JSON DATA }
 </body>
</html>
```

In order to remove this, we can simply get the body content as given below.

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("URL").ignoreContentType(true);       
connection.execute();

String strJsonData = connection.get().body().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about jsoup, but if it's valid JSON, then Gson should be able to decode (may need some custom deserializers for your custom classes).

If it's not valid JSON and you are getting errors, then there is a bug in jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many answers and people writing pages worth of code, I have no idea why  but you can do this easly with GSON.

```
/**
 * Convert json string to json object
 */
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

private JsonObject getResAsJson(String response) {
    return new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be GSON?

Comment: Kindly read the API docs  https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html

 Also you can look up com.google.gson.JsonParser;

Comment: Okay - how is this better than the existing GSON answers?

Comment: It is not better, just a different way to do it, that is all.