# JSoup: Requesting JSON response

Tags: java, json, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to authenticate then connect to a website. Some URL have a JSON response  (because part of the site is in AJAX). Can JSoup handle JSON response ?

```
Connection.Response doc = Jsoup.connect("...")
                               .data(...)
                               .cookie(...)
                               .header(...)
                               .method(Method.POST)
                               .execute();
String result = doc.body()
```

In my case body is "".

- Is it because JSoup don't know how to handle JSON ? (offcourse there is no )
- Or because there is an error in my request ?

Is there JSoup like libraries for JSON ?

Comment: Try to use this: `.header("Accept", "application/json")`

Answer (score 61):

You can fetch JSON or other data format using this:

```
// JSON example
String json = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
```

Answer (score 7):

**Try Like This**

*Use Header "Accept:text/javascript"*

```
 String InboxJson=Jsoup.connect("https://www.fiverr.com/conversations/Json")
                            .timeout(1000000) 
                            .header("Accept", "text/javascript")
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0")
                            .get()
                            .body()
                            .text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jsoup will execute Javascript. If the provided URL returns any non-html text, I believe Jsoup will just wrap it in a body tag or something similiar.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348633/reading-json-content/6348828#6348828) for a suggestion

Comment: Yes, of course, JavaScript is not executed. I was not sure if the JSON string will be wrapped in a body tag or if it would be removed to suit a well formed document.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON library to process JSON Data.

Here are some: [Click](https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/wiki/Benchmark)