# How can I do a jsoup request with array data? Jsoup post request with array data and get json from php server

Tags: java, php, android, jsoup

I get json data with postman. Screenshot is the following.
But I could't get json data with jsoup.
How can I post a request with array data by using jsoup?

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd", "blockchain");
$cur_key ="";
$cur_key = $_POST['cur_key'];
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM crypto where id IN('".implode("','",$cur_key)."')";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    $encode = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $encode[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($encode);

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
?>
```

[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKnaJ.jpg)

My java code is like the following.

```
    try {

           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(_url).header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                    .data("cur_key[]", "bitcoin")
                    .data("cur_key[]", "ripple")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .timeout(0).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No errors. But response is blank.

Comment: How do you check if response is blank? Your response is in json format.  Have you checked how to handle json reponse in jsoup, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133118/jsoup-requesting-json-response