# Unable to invoke no-args constructor, gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm getting this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface javax.xml.crypto.Data. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`

when I run the code in this class:

```
public class FinderClass {

    InputStream input;
    Reader reader;
    Data data;

    public FinderClass()
    {

    }

    public double findOtherWeapon(double weaponPrice) throws IOException
    {

        input = new URL("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=quantity&sort_dir=desc&appid=730").openStream();
        reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
        data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Data.class);                 System.out.println("data");
        return -1;
    }
```

Even though I have a no-args constructor, it's still giving me this error.  I've looked up how to use an `InstanceCreator`, but I don't really understand how to implement it.  Could someone explain how to do this?

Comment: I think you may have imported the wrong `Data` class. Did you really want something from the crypto package (as opposed to your own bean)?

Comment: @Thilo Hmm... I got the whole block from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348828/4566760), and Eclipse only suggests to import either `javax.xml.crypto.Data` or `com.sun.jna.platform.unix.X11.XClientMessageEvent.Data`, neither of which are from Gson.  Either one causes the same exception, though, and `com.google.gson.Data` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You are supposed to write your own bean class to match the JSON data structure. `Data` was just a placeholder name in the linked question.

Comment: @Thilo, Wow, I should really read the posts more thoroughly... Thanks.